Font Size Discrepancy in Fillable PDF Form Between pdftk and Apple Preview
I am working with a fillable PDF form and have encountered an issue with font sizes. When I fill out the fields directly using Apple Preview, the font sizes appear significantly different compared to when I fill the same fields using pdftk.
Screenshot
It seems that Apple Preview applies some formatting automatically as I type, which is not being applied when using pdftk.
Does anyone know how I can ensure that the font size remains consistent between pdftk and Apple Preview? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
